# Comparing unique columns in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table that contains columns with a unique id, company name, and year. It looks like

```
Id | company name  | year

1  | industry one  | 1991

2  | industry two. | 1992
```

It's a huge list that continues on like this. I need to know a few things which companies existed in one year and not in another. For example if a company existed in 1991 and not 1992. If a company existed in both years. And if a company existed in 1992 and not 1991. I'm not sure how to write the formulas to gather the data I need.

Comment: If a company existed in 91 and 92, I'm guessing that there are two entries of this company in the list, one with 1991 and one with 1992. And they aren't necessarily following each other in terms of ID. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Your question is very ambiguous because you don't describe the range of conditions that apply.  Is everything limited to 1991 and 1992 or is there a range of years and combinations, and potential intervening years?  You mention both companies and industries.  Are industry one and two just company names or an additional hierarchy that needs to be addressed?  How many records can there be per company (only either one or two, or some larger number, and if so, what rules apply)?  What is the output you're looking for?

Comment: You can do a lot of analysis with a pivot table: add company name to row labels, year to column headers and e.g. count of company to values

Comment: You could also look it up with a `index`. Say that you want the information on when *industry one* existed. So you enter the name of the industry in an empty cell, say `D1` Then in `E1` you enter `=INDEX($A$1:$C$200,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$200=$D$1,ROW($B$1:$B$200)),ROW(1:1)),3)`  and then drag it down a few cells. *Assuming* that *industry one* is in cell `B2` and so on. 
And if you want to instead show what companies existed 1991. You enter 1991 in `D1` instead, but then you need to change the function to `=INDEX($A$1:$C$200,SMALL(IF($C$1:$C$200=$D$1,ROW($C$1:$C$200)),ROW(1:1)),2)` and drag down.

Comment: To get the above to work, you also need to press "ctrl + shift + enter" after entering the formula. It will then get curly brackets { } around it.

Comment: Fixer ~ industry one and two are indeed company names. There are many years listed in a row from 1970 - 2016.  A company name could occur once per year but it would have the same id. The idea is that between two consecutive years I need to know which companies were new and which were removed and which remained unchanged.

Comment: Christopher ~ I'm not sure how to further sort the data to accomplish my end goal using index.

Comment: Well if you want to explore it, the source of that function was over at https://blog.udemy.com/vlookup-multiple-values/ If that helps you. But I guess it depends on how you want to access and display the information.